# How do I set my variable correctly to a value on Firebase and not have it reset the progress?

Tags: swift, firebase, restart, saving-data

Everytime I leave this ViewController and then come back the quiz starts back to question 1.  I want it to resume from where I left off.

I believe why it keeps resetting to zero is because my initial "questionNumber" is set to 0 but I'm not sure how to set its value to the value in Firebase correctly. I get error after error.  I've tried so many different ways but none of them seem to work and resume from where I left off. 
Thanks for your help! PLEASE help me!

```java
class CryptoViewController: UIViewController {

    var questionList = CryptoBank()
    var score = 0
    var pickedQuestion = 0
    var uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    var questionNumber = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var questionViewer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var choiceOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choiceTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choiceThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionNumberView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBarView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        choiceOne.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        choiceTwo.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        choiceThree.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
       update()
    }


    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            pickedQuestion = 1}
        else if sender.tag == 2 {
            pickedQuestion = 2}
        else if sender.tag == 3 {
            pickedQuestion = 3}
        checkAnswer()
        questionNumber += 1
        nextQuestion()
    }

    func checkAnswer(){
        let correctAnswer = questionList.cryptoBank[questionNumber].answer
        if pickedQuestion == correctAnswer {
            score += 1
        }else{
            print("Wrong Answer")
        }
    }

    func updateFirebase(){
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid else{
            return}
        ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("Cryptoquiz").child("Question Number").setValue(questionNumber)
        ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("Cryptoquiz").child("Score").setValue(score)
    }

    func nextQuestion(){
        if questionNumber <= 9 {
            update()
        } else{

            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Done!", message: "Would you like to restart?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                self.startAgain()
            })
            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }}

    func update(){
        let nextQuest = questionList.cryptoBank[questionNumber]
        questionViewer.text = nextQuest.question
        choiceOne.setTitle(nextQuest.choice1, for: .normal)
        choiceTwo.setTitle(nextQuest.choice2, for: .normal)
        choiceThree.setTitle(nextQuest.choice3, for: .normal)
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        questionNumberView.text = "Question: \(questionNumber + 1)"
        progressBarView.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width/9)  * CGFloat(questionNumber + 1)
        updateFirebase()

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save your progress in `UserDefaults` in `viewDidDisappear()` like this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(questionNumber, forKey: "questionNumber")
```

And then every time you open your view, in `viewDidLoad()` or in `viewDidAppear()` you update your questionNumber like this:

```
let questionNumberSaved = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: “questionNumber”) ?? 0
questionNumber = questionNumberSaved
```

Then after doing this you call your `updateFirebase()` method

Comment: I did like you said and tried a few other things but it's still always resetting to 0 when returning to the viewController. Thanks for trying to help....I appreciate it alot.

Comment: Where did you put loading scores code? And where did you try to save questionNumber? Did you print question number after you loaded it from user defaults?

Comment: I update the questionNumber var in Firebase, in the updateFirebase func I created.  I've tried to print out statements in various places a to see when it resets to 0.  For what what I understand it switches to 0 not when I go back to the quiz choice page but when I return to this page.  Firebase's data reverts back to 0 when I click on the quiz I want to take.  The inital value when I set up questionNumber is 0 but everything I try to get it set to the value in Firebase doesn't work.  I've tried to reset it in viewDidLoad to the firebase value but it never works. It still resets to 0

Comment: What does it print after this line `let questionNumberSaved = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: “questionNumber”) ?? 0`

Comment: Still 0...the only time time questionNumber changes to the correct number is when I'm on that viewController. aznguitarist/Cryptoknowledge is my github.

Comment: Are you sure you did save question number in UserDefaults? Try placing this `UserDefaults.standard.set(questionNumber, forKey: "questionNumber")` inside your `updateFirebase()` method